# How do I use %s multiple times

Tags: python

```
import time 
import sys
print ("Welcome to the annoying machine. Made by Bloody")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Here you will enjoy this annoying thingy.")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Have fun!")
time.sleep(2)
password = input("Enter new password:")
time.sleep(2)
print ("Your password is %s, remmeber this." % password)
name = input ("What is your name?")
time.sleep (1)
```

I have this and want to use %s for 2 things. How do I do this?

Comment: give an example

Comment: may be you are trying something like print('name is %s and password is %s'%(name,password))

Answer (score 3):

Pass a tuple as the argument after the `%` operator.

```
print("Your name and password are: %s, %s" % (name, password))
```

This is called (old) [printf-style String Formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting), and it can get pretty fancy.